# Is "Unless you had told me about Sue's hair, I wouldn't have noticed it" correct and natural-sounding?

Tags: conditionals, conditional-perfect, unless

I find it natural to say "If you hadn't told me about Sue's hair, I wouldn't have noticed it", but when *if-not* is substituted with *unless* in this specific sentence it sounds weird.
I've found a similarly-constructed sentence that for some reason sounds more natural:
He wouldn't have survived unless a stranger had rescued him.
But I can't pin down the specific reason why the latter example sounds more natural to me. So is there a difference that makes the second example more correct or is it just that my English instinct is a little off on this one?

Comment: I don't like *he wouldn't have survived unless a stranger had rescued him* that much, either.

Comment: Now that I take another look at the sentence, I find that awkward as well.

Comment: "If you hadn't told me about Sue's hair ..."

Answer (score 3):

What is wrong is that this is a situation where you can't use *unless*. From [Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/unless),

> **unless**: Except if (used to introduce the case in which a statement being made is not true or valid):
>   *unless you have a photographic memory, repetition is vital.*

In your example, the statement *"you had told me about Sue's hair"* is presumably indeed valid, so it can't be introduced with *unless*.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks! It's just that while researching into this topic I came across a few websites/forums that say you can use "unless + Subject + had" to mean "if + Subject + hadn't". One of the articles even gave an example: "They wouldn't have come over unless we'd invited them" = "They wouldn't have come over if we had not invited them." I guess that's wrong, too?

Comment: *"They wouldn't have come over unless we'd invited them"* is perfectly fine if they didn't come over (and in fact, it implies it). And *"They wouldn't have come over if we hadn't invited them"* implies that they did come over.

Comment: And in cases with general truths, like *"Birds will sing if there are no hawks nearby"* or *"Birds will sing unless there are hawks nearby",* *unless* and *if not* are equivalent.

Answer (score -1):

This is gramatically incorrect, because it lacks *parallel construction* (here's a [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelism_(grammar))).

Briefly put, linked items in a sentence should have similar grammatical forms.

In

> Unless you had told me about Sue's hair

the verb *had* is not negated, but in

> I wouldn't have noticed it

*wouldn't* is negated.

The alternative you give

> If you hadn't told me about Sue's hair, I wouldn't have noticed it

does not have this problem, and is the correct construction.

Comment: There's no grammatical requirement for parallel sentences to be ***that*** parallel. Can you show me anybody who criticizes Tennyson's line from *Ulysses* "to strive, to seek, to find, and not to yield" on the grounds that it is insufficiently parallel? Or any reference saying that adding a *not* to a parallel structure makes it ungrammatical, for that matter.

Comment: -1: I don't believe there is any grammatical requirement for consistency with negatives in parallel structures in English. As a native English speaker, I don't find this kind of inconsistency ungrammatical, as I do other kinds of inconsistency in parallel structures.  Do you have any references that say this is ungrammatical, as I asked you for in a previous comment?

Comment: It's more than a little silly to language-lawyer English as if it were C++. There are no absolutely absolute absolutes; it's all a matter of degree. The Tennyson line is poetic license, and you could say the "parallelism" comes from the poem's meter. Introducing "Unless" in the second example creates a double negative, so in balance it's worse than the non parallel construction.

Comment: The [Purdue Owl](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/623/01/) website specifically gives as an example of good parallel structure something that would be considered ungrammatical per your answer. See the first example in Clauses: *The coach told the players that they should get a lot of sleep, that they should **not** eat too much, and that they should do some warm-up exercises before the game.*

Comment: Again: English. Not C++.    In OP's original example, there is nothing else to link the two clauses _except_ the negation.  In all of your examples, there is something else.

Comment: So you're not actually going to be able to find a reference saying that this is ungrammatical, are you?

Comment: I'm not even going to try; you're overthinking it.  Over and out.